# Power shell replace character Ž

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I have a power shell script that basically replace specific characters e.g (TM) -- > '™' in all the files under a specific folder.

The script works perfectly. But it's not working when I tried to replace *avŽ* with *avé*. If I try to replace *av* with *ac* it works. So I am assuming replace is not working for **grapheme Ž** character. it will be great if you can provide some idea on this. Below is the sample code which replace the character:

```
$old = 'PavŽ'
$new = 'Pavé 
$InputFiles = Get-Item "C:\..\..\*.txt"   
Get-Item $InputFiles | ForEach {
        (Get-Content -Path $_.FullName).Replace($old,$new) | Set-Content -Path $_.FullName
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Powershell replaces any character just fine. But there may be some other issues:

- The encoding of your file may be the issue. (most likely).
  If your file is encoded using a code page that doen't contain certain
  characters, those characters won't get saved.
  You may want to consider saving your files in a format that *does*, e.g. UTF-8.
- You may not have write rights to some files.

In my small test, the replacement worked just fine. I used notepad to create a file containing 'PavŽ', and another containing 'Pavé'.

Your few lines of powershell replaced everything (and with $old en $new switched) back and forth just fine.

Comment: Thanks, @realbart....2nd point should not be an issue as it's able to replace other charters...may be I have an issue with file encoding.

Comment: I am voting your answer as correct. File is encoded in Mac machine.